# Google Sheets Dragging part of a formula while keeping the rest intact

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this formula in Google Sheets: `=ROUND((J2*2)*('Sheetname'!C39/100))` 
I want to keep the `(J2*2)` consistent as I drag down;
at the same time I want to have `('Sheetname'!C39/100))` adjust to the next row as in `('Sheetname'!C40/100))` etc...

Answer (score 2):

Use the `$` sign to make it constant. if you want to make column constant place `$` before column name if you want to make row constant put `$` before the row value

**To Use J2 cell value in all the computation**

`=ROUND(($J$2*2)*('Sheetname'!C39/100))`

**To Use J column value in all the computation, but change row based on drag**

`=ROUND(($J2*2)*('Sheetname'!C39/100))`

**To Use 2nd row value in all the computation, but change column based on drag**

`=ROUND((J$2*2)*('Sheetname'!C39/100))`